# Parsing geocoded data using python

Tags: python, google-maps-api, pandas

I am trying to create a .csv file of parsed information of geocoded data from the google API geocoding service. I want to parse out the address information to be in separate columns. My script runs fine till location data where I get Type error. Can anyone help me and modify my script so that I can include this data into my table?

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests 
import geocoder
import time 
import json 
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/albertgonzalobautista/Desktop/workingbook.csv') # define CSV to be read to be geocdoed 

    # create new columns for the output CSV 
    df['geocode_data'] = ''
    df['address']=''
    df['street_number']=''
    df['street_name']=''
    df['postalcode']=''
    df['city']=''
    df['st_pr_mn']=''
    df['country']=''
    df['location_lat']=''
    df['location_lon']=''

    # Create function that handles the geocoding requests 

    average = 0
    def reverseGeocode(latlng): #defines reverse geocoding function 
        #Set parameters
        start = time.time()
        result = {} #create empty list 
        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0}&key={1}' #Access URL for Google Geocoder API 
        apikey = 'XXX' # Set you API Key taken from Google API website and your Google Developers Account 
        request = url.format(latlng, apikey) 
        #delays responses so that it does not over     
        data = json.loads(requests.get(request).text)
        if len(data['results']) > 0:
            result = data['results'][0]
        #global average #if not work delete first char(uncomment)
        average = time.time() - start

        return  result

    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if average < 0.3 : time.sleep(0.3 - average) #0.3 is period time (min= 0.2 max = free)

        df['geocode_data'][i] = reverseGeocode(df['lat'][i].astype(str) + ',' + df['lon'][i].astype(str))


    for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'address_components' in row['geocode_data']:
        for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
            df['address'][i] = row['geocode_data']['formatted_address']

        for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
            if 'street_number' in component['types']:
                df['street_number'][i] = component['long_name']

        for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
            if 'route' in component ['types']:
                df['street_name'][i] = component['long_name']
                break
        for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
            if 'route' in component ['types']:
                df['street_name'][i] = component['long_name'] 

        for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
            if 'postal_code' in component ['types']:
                df['postalcode'][i] = component['short_name']
                break

        for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
            if 'locality' in component ['types']:
                df['city'][i]= component['short_name']
                break

        for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
            if 'administrative_area_level_1' in component ['types']:
                df['st_pr_mn'][i] = component ['long_name']  
                break

        for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
            if 'country' in component ['types']:
                df['country'][i] = component ['long_name']
                break

        for component in row['geocode_data']['geometry']:
          if component['location']:
                df['location_lng'][i] = int(component['location']['lng'])
                df['location_lat'][i] = int(component['location']['lat'])

    df.to_csv('test10.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

#sample data that I am trying to parse
{'geometry': {'viewport': {'southwest': {'lng': 4.947849719708499, 'lat': 52.36571761970851}, 'northeast': {'lng': 4.950547680291502, 'lat': 52.3684155802915}}, 'location': {'lng': 4.9491987, 'lat': 52.3670666}, 'location_type': 'ROOFTOP'}, 'address_components': [{'long_name': '114', 'types': ['street_number'], 'short_name': '114'}, {'long_name': 'Zeeburgerpad', 'types': ['route'], 'short_name': 'Zeeburgerpad'}, {'long_name': 'Amsterdam-Oost', 'types': ['sublocality_level_1', 'sublocality', 'political'], 'short_name': 'Amsterdam-Oost'}, {'long_name': 'Amsterdam', 'types': ['locality', 'political'], 'short_name': 'Amsterdam'}, {'long_name': 'Amsterdam', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political'], 'short_name': 'Amsterdam'}, {'long_name': 'Noord-Holland', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political'], 'short_name': 'NH'}, {'long_name': 'Netherlands', 'types': ['country', 'political'], 'short_name': 'NL'}, {'long_name': '1019 AE', 'types': ['postal_code'], 'short_name': '1019 AE'}], 'place_id': 'ChIJD14pyz8JxkcRF1Kpg8opql4', 'formatted_address': 'Zeeburgerpad 114, 1019 AE Amsterdam, Netherlands', 'types': ['street_address']}
```

Comment: Put your full error message in the question, in particular what line it occurs.

Comment: File "/Users/albertgonzalobautista/GEOPY.py", line 98, in <module>
  if component['location']:

builtins.TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `if component['location']:`? The line before `for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:`presumably returns a list of strings. You are trying to address `component` like a dictionary and therefore get the error, since parts of strings can only be adressed with integers up to the length of the string.